# Unmarshaling matched nodes at any level in the xml

Tags: xml, go

Im trying to unmarshal an xml and extract specific nodes out of it, which can be at several different levels. 
For example, such Xml is valid:

```
<People>
            <Person>
                <FullName>Jerome Anthony</FullName>
            </Person>
            <a>
            <Person>
            <FullName>Christina</FullName>
            </Person>
        </a>
        </People>
```

I would like to extract all FullName from this xml, regardless of their nesting level.
Example code  I tried, which is not working:

```
type People struct {
    Names []string `xml:"FullName"`
}
v := People{Names: []string{}}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Names of people: %q", v)
```

Remark: This is a simple example for unmarshaling strings, effectively I would like to also unmarshal complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that People has no child named FullName. It has, however, a child named "a" that has a child named FullName.

There's a working example right in the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#example_Unmarshal.

Comment: You're correct, and that is the problem Im facing. If I specify `xml:"Person>FullName"`, The result will be `Jerome Anthony`, while if I specify `xml:"a>Person>FullName"`, The result will be `Christina`. I want to consolidate both to the same value. I want to do similar to xpath, where you can build an expression that says "Give me any node, no matter the nesting level, that is named `FullName`

Comment: @buddy123, you could do [just](https://godoc.org/?q=xpath) [that](https://godoc.org/?q=etree).